# Movie about a musician who becomes a teacher

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember everything about the movie except the name. The hero/protaganist is a struggling musician who lives in the suburbs with his wife. This is around the 1950's. To make ends meet, he takes a summer job in the local college/university to teach music to students .  One thing leads to another and he becomes permanent staff. He is a bit of rebel and he motivates students by letting them hear rock and telling its classical history. He asks why they like a particular song and it is made clear because it is a simple rythmm to catch and it goes on and on.

After his child is born, pretty early it is diagnosed that the child is deaf. Times change (1960's now) and things comes to a head when one night our musician comes to know that one of the beatles is dead and he becomes sad or is mildly depressed. He thinks the son wouldn't know what significant role the Beatles played as a group in society as well as specifically in music.

The son with help of mother uses sign language to tell that he knows what they stood for. Later the musician makes up to the son by making a song and dedicating it to his son in public and calling him 'Sweet boy' and taking his name.

At the end of the movie, he is ambushed where all students from his years come and do his musical classical music piece that he has been composing over the years.

Does anybody know the movie I'm talking about?

Comment: I was so hoping this would be School of Rock

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[*Mr. Holland's Opus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Holland%27s_Opus) from 1995 is the film you're looking for. It stars Richard Dreyfus as the title character. Beautiful film.

> In Portland, Oregon in 1965, Glenn Holland is a talented musician and composer who has been relatively successful in the exhausting life of a professional musical performer. However, in an attempt to enjoy more free time with his young wife, Iris, and to enable him to compose a piece of orchestral music, the 30-year-old Holland accepts a teaching position at John F. Kennedy High School.
>
> Unfortunately for Holland, he is soon forced to realize that his position as a music teacher makes him a marginalized figure in the faculty's hierarchy. Many of his colleagues, and some in Kennedy High's administration, including the school's principal Helen Jacobs and vice principal Gene Wolters, resent Holland and question the value and importance of music education given the school's strained budget. However, he quickly begins to win many of his colleagues over. Holland finds success using rock and roll as a way to make classical music more accessible to his students.
>
> Holland's lack of quality time with Iris becomes problematic when their son, Cole, is diagnosed as deaf. Holland reacts with hostility to the news that he can never teach the joys of music to his own child. Iris willingly learns American Sign Language to communicate with her son, but Holland resists. This causes further estrangement within the family.

Here's the trailer for it:

Comment: Video unavailable.

Comment: Same problem here. But here's another one that works for me. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPt_INy_CtM

Comment: Wow, this is one of my favorite movies, and I think the trailer and summary give too much away.